# Rails and Devise: set Secure flag when requested via HTTPS, don't set Secure flag when not requested via HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, https, devise

I manage a Rails 4.2 application which runs dual stack: SSL and Non-SSL. I'd like to set the Secure flag for cookies when the resource is requested via HTTPS and I want to leave out the flag when the resource is requested via plain HTTP.

Is there a way to achieve this in Rails (session cookie, cookies sent manually in the Code)? And especially when using Devise with rememberable enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response, but I'm currently looking into the same thing and it seems https://github.com/mobalean/devise_ssl_session_verifiable should automate this for you, although it uses a different approach (regular session cookie over http + https, but an additional secure cookie in https, so that someone hijacking your session cannot access your https-only resources.